# Swift 3 initialization for Type causes a leak

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, initialization

I am trying to initialize an object by it's type.
After initializing it, it seems the object is being leaked for some reason...

The code:

`let classType = someClassType`

`return classType.init(params)`

now the class type I am returning is conforming to a protocol with a required init with params.

I don't understand why this doesn't work it suppose to be legit...

Would be glad to receive any help.

Thanks,
Gal

Answer (score 0):

I hope this snippet could help you.

```
let tipo = String.self

let aString: String = tipo.init("hola")

print(aString)
```

Comment: I need to receive type in a function which I don't know which type I will receive. it needs to be a type conforming to a protocol.